# Chef File Ruby search_file_replace_line in php.ini regex

Tags: php, ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I'm trying to search for the existence of the following line in a file;

default_mimetype = "text/html"

and then if found uncommented-out as above, then comment it out like so;

;default_mimetype = "text/html"

I currently have the following Chef recipe;

```
ruby_block "php_ini" do
    block do
        file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/php.ini")
        file.search_file_replace_line(/default_mimetype = "text/html"/, ';default_mimetype = "text/html"')
        file.write_file
    end
end

service "apache2" do
    action :restart
end
```

but the file_search_replace_line line is causing a syntax error (probably due to the "s & the ; ) How do I need to write this line so that it does what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Managing a file like this is not recommended, as it allows all kinds of non-convergent behavior and is generally very hard to reason about. A better approach is to use a `template` resource to completely control the content of the file, which means you always know what will be in it rather than depending on what happened to be there before Chef ran (usually a distro-provided file).

As to the specifics, the issue is the `/` in `text/html`, make that `text\/html`.